# Stack Overflow, why don't you like pleasantries?

Tags: discussion, edits, down-votes

[image: Edit on question]

Why would someone remove a statement of appreciation and downvote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665943/java-jdbc-issue-row-1-doesnt-contain-data-for-all-columns)? I understand it's a technical site, but I think there should be room for pleasantries, after all we are asking for help.

Also, no one was able to answer my problem, I solved it myself and provided documentation how I fixed my issue and my answer was also downvoted. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Lol, of course it had to be GEOCHET... he's a one issue user, on a crusade to rid Stack Overflow of any and all pleasantries.

Comment: I doubt the down-votes are related to the pleasantries.

Comment: Well, I am sure everyone has different opinions on this. Like I said I understand the concept of this being a network for questions and answers. But I think this where we IT people get a bad rep for being weird. If there's a system of points, and everyone wants to get more points for answering questions why would you downvote a question  simply for asking a question like a normal human being. It seems kinda deuschy. But I guess when in Rome do as the Romans...

Comment: @DuncanJones what are the downvotes for then.....

Comment: @EduardoDennis Sadly the nature of this site is - we can't be sure. Somebody came past your question and down-voted. We may never know why.

Comment: A likely reason is lack of research.  This has been bought up a number of times, there is information in the FAQ about it, etc.

Comment: Plus, if every question with "thanks" and such were downvoted, there'd be a lot of downvoted questions.  The "thanks" in posts do annoy me a bit, but I never downvote for that reason alone.

Comment: @Servy I'm pretty sure Eduardo is talking about [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665943/java-jdbc-issue-row-1-doesnt-contain-data-for-all-columns), not this one.

Comment: @DuncanJones haha ok thanks, well it definitely has some getting used to lol I am sure this is something a lot of users experience when they first start asking questions..

Comment: I'm OK with just a "thanks" or "hi".. it's anthing else that gets noisy

Comment: @Adel: Like signatures, right?  I also don't like "here's my code" because, clearly, the code is right below.

Comment: @EduardoDennis - Downvote on Meta mean we love you. They are opposite to downvotes on SO-proper.

Comment: @Servy See this is is a prime example of how people that think that know it all and they don't. Look how many people have tagged this as a duplicate question. But just because they failed to do any research. If you go to those questions its talking about the entry Hi, hi guys, etc .. Which I get takes up space in the preview etc, but I posted a picture of a technical question, my proposed thoughts on what might be causing it and a pleasantry at the end.. Which in no way affects the preview, this is not talked about in the other posts. Servy thought I was complaining about this question LOL WTF

Comment: @EduardoDennis The post also talks about signatures (aka taglines), thanks, and specifically mentions both the top and bottom of the post.  So yes, it is talked about in the linked duplicate, along with lots of other meta questions specifically talking about several of those specific points, if there isn't enough reading for you in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @EduardoDennis  - See but as juergen says below - it takes a bit of time .Keep the pleasantries to a simple "thanks" at the end

Comment: and even to take this question as an example, my question has gotten 7 downvotes yet juergens condescending short answer about this is not a social network has gotten 10 upvotes its almost like stackoverflow promotes these short jerky, snobbish answers.. I think us a group of IT people would get so much further and people would love us so much more if we knew how to interact better...

Comment: @Servy you thought I was complaining about this question! What are you talking about research if you cant comprehend three sentences haha

Comment: @EduardoDennis - See, Meta is the hangout for moderators and *slightly* over-confident people. Your proposal is just too subjective.  The fact is, in this context the edit you linked makes sense . or at least change it to a simple "thanks" to make compromise...  At the end of the day, Stack is striving to run away from anything reddit/facebook..

Comment: @EduardoDennis Please don't go there. You should simply have researched this question on Meta a bit better. And juergen's answer was just concise in the beginning and he expanded it later on. Things are not always perfect, but you seem to be a bit upset at the moment. Which might be a good indication to move away for a while.

Comment: @Bart Not at all Bart, I think its just something I experience all the time. I thought since we were already on the subject I would express I how I felt. It is not meant to be harmful to anyone or anything just an observation. We in the IT field, myself included, are not the best at interacting with people. Just though pleasantries makes interactions more pleasant.

Comment: @EduardoDennis If you're going to insult me and laugh at me for taking the time to explain why your meta post was downvoted, saying that it was offtopic (when you then proceeded to complain about the downvotes on your meta question and say that you don't understand why they're there) it's not exactly a good sign to others.  It makes people not want to help you, and also makes them want to downvote your posts due to an unconstructive attitude.

Comment: Time to relax everyone. Here's [a picture of a unicorn](http://blog.urbanoutfitters.co.uk/wp-content/posts/2012/12/unicorn.jpg). He's happy because he doesn't take the Internet too seriously :-)

Comment: @EduardoDennis If it's any consolation, I simply always assume users are thankful. ;)

Comment: Yea sorry about all that whining haha lol ummm kinda weird what fake points will make you do :-/

Comment: @EduardoDennis - Oh that is the truth buddy ;-) sigh

Comment: @DuncanJones - thank for that buzz, nice one

Comment: @Duncan unicorn might not be enough, [Narwhal](http://th06.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/i/2013/064/8/b/sea_unicorn_by_doodleforfood-d5x3qap.jpg) is also needed!

Answer (score 25):

This is no social network. We focus here on Questions & Answers only.

Everything else is just noise and unnecessary for answering a question.

Personally I remove those phrases too and I don't like them actually. It takes me time to read them and I have to filter that out when I try to get the essence of a question. Often questions start with

> Hi, greating to all of you. I love Stack Overflow. I'm a newbie. I just learn SQL. I have no idea how to solve this. I googled for hours. Now I need your help.....

They are meant to be nice and that is fine. But it is just not necessary.

Future visitors having the same problem as you need to understand your question and see if they have the same problem. We want questions and answer be helpful, and in best case straight to the point.

<sub>That being said I hope this answer is helpful to you. Thanks you all for the upvotes. I also want to thank my mom for raising me. Have a good one till next time. Bye. Kind regards Juergen from Germany but actually soon from Argentina again. Looking forward to it....</sub>

Comment: It's especially annoying at the start of questions because it consumes the whole preview, a small tip shown on the list of questions when you hover over a question to decide whether or not to read it. That first few sentences is vital and MUST contain information specific to this question.

Comment: Oh the irony in [this suggested edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19367)! @psu you know you can untick the "this edit was helpful" to insta-reject those. By leaving it ticked you insta-approved it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I did one and gave him the benefit of the doubt that he happened to find sometihng that needed fixed, but saw he was doing it multiple times and wanted to mention it to him.  If he did it a 3rd time, I would have done exactly that.

Comment: @juergend how is Argentina? ;)